# When to add -1 to array recursion?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, limit

I can't understand one thing, when do I need to add `-1` to `arr.length` and when I don't need to add `-1`?

For example, this code will only work **if I add** `-1`:

```
public boolean array220(int[] nums, int index) {
    if(index >= nums.length - 1)
        return false;
    if(nums[index] * 10 == nums[index + 1])
        return true;

    return array220(nums, index + 1);
}
```

And this code will only work **if I won't add** `-1`:

```
public int array11(int[] nums, int index) {
    if(index >= nums.length)
        return 0;
    if(nums[index] == 11)
        return 1 + array11(nums, index + 1);

    return array11(nums, index + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you access elements of the array using both `nums[index]` *and* `nums[index+1]`.

Since the array lookup value must be `< nums.length`, the constraint is:

```
index+1 < nums.length
```

aka:

```
index < nums.length - 1
```

which means you exclusion logic is the reverse test:

```
if (index >= nums.length - 1)
```

---

In the second example, you only access `nums[index]`, so:

```
index < nums.length
```

giving exclusion logic as:

```
if (index >= nums.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since arrays are zero-based, `arr.length` is the *size* of the array, in the number of elements. This means that the last index is at `arr.length-1`, since `0` is the first element.

There's no clear cut rules, as for example if you use `>=` instead of `>` (or more usually `<=` vs. `<`, like in a simple for loop) you need to adjust your values.

Comment: You're missing the main point, which is that `-1` is needed because of the `+1` in `nums[index+1]`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45772244/5221149).

Comment: I didn't really want to comment on the example code, as you can write code that works with all kinds of additions and subtractions from the index. Considering the question he seems to think there is some clear cut rule, but I addressed the main point of array size vs. last index.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is empty, it contains 0 elements and the length is 0.

If your array has 1 element in 0 index, **then the length is 1**.

If your array has 2 elements **in 0 and 1 indexes**, **then the length is 2.**

and so on..

we can notice , that the first index of every array is 0 so the last index is always array.length-1.

therefore we can use two methods

- first method
  :if you want to use <

so the code will be something like (note that in the end , `i` will be equal to array.length-1)

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
```

- second method:if you want to use <=

so the code will be something like (note that in the end , `i` will also be equal to array.length-1)

```
for(int i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++)
```